# Class global variables for inheriting classes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, global-variables

I'm trying to create a class with some global parameters that need to be configured using some class method for all instances of the the class and a second class which inherit from the previous class and configure itself using the same configuration method...

Now, this is a bit confusing; here's a first example:

```
class cc_a(object):
    v1 = 0
    v2 = 0
    v3 = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_v1(cls, vv = 0):
        cls.v1 = vv

c1 = cc_a()
c2 = cc_a()

print c1.v1, c2.v1

c1.set_v1(100)

print c1.v1, c2.v1
```

In this first example the code correctly prints `0 0` before the configuration and `100 100` after the class configuration, great!

Now, classes inheriting from the prev class should behave in a similar manner, but should not *interfere* with the original class. Here's another bit of code:

```
class cc_a(object):
    v1 = 0
    v2 = 0
    v3 = 0

    @classmethod
    def set_v1(cls, vv = 0):
        cls.v1 = vv


class cc_10(cc_a):
    cc_a.set_v1(10)

class cc_20(cc_a):
    cc_a.set_v1(20)

c1 = cc_a()
c2 = cc_10()
c3 = cc_20()

print c1.v1, c2.v1, c3.v1
```

this unfortunately prints `20 20 20` instead of the intended `0 10 20`

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: You are *specifically* referencing `cc_a` in the sub-classes; what did you expect would happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, I know, but I can't call `cc_10.set_v1(10)` for example as cc_10 is not in its own scope....

Answer (score 0):

For the behaviour you expect, the following would work:

```
class cc_10(cc_a):
    v1 = 10
```

This will inherit `v2` and `v3` from the superclass, but overrides `v1`. Alternatively, call `set_v1` on the subclass *after* you've finished defining it:

```
class cc_10(cc_a):
    pass

cc_10.set_v1(10)
```